# Getting error as soon as app starts "UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined" using .Net core 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.AuthorityHelpers.BuildAuthority(MicrosoftIdentityOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.WebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(JwtBearerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Please provide more details. I hope you are trying to configure the jwtOptions in `startup.cs` and that is where this exception is thrown. please post the src code in it. You can find my answer helpful if it applies to your error directly.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the reason was the missing "https://" in the configs of the appsettings.json file.
Just adding it to the instance worked.

Contents of appsettings.json:

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    //"Instance": "blah.b2clogin.com", // <- Missing "https://"
    "Instance": "https://blah.b2clogin.com", // <- Fixed version
    "ClientId": "f6fc311c-cf68-4264-9da6-a3aae9727821",
    "Domain": "blah.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signupsignin"
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error usually happens when a string without http:// or https:// is provided as an argument to `new Uri(string)`. To avoid throwing an exception you can use,

```cs
 new Uri(urlString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```